# Jenkinsfile : Posting test info back to github?

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Jenkinsfile to build build pull requests (declarative pipeline) , I want to push test results (one line) , code coverage(cobertura) and if possible SONAR back into the pull request in a fairly simple fashion.

I looked at some docs and added

`junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml`

but it doesn't post anything back to the pull request in github.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cannot push test results back to GitHub without actually using git commit/push. What you can actually do is to create a webhook ([setup guide](https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/jenkins/github/2015/04/17/github-jenkins/)) on GitHub and on Jenkins so that the build result is showed on GitHub and clicking on that link can redirect you to the Jenkins server.

Example
[image]

For Sonar I am sure there is a webhook as well, but I haven't used it personally.

Comment: How do you get feedbacj that 37 run , 0 skipped and 0 failed - I just see that it was successful and don't get that one line feedback